# In the next year vs. For the next year vs. Over the next year

Tags: prepositions, descriptive-grammar

I want to know the differences among these three:

1. In the next year
2. For the next year
3. Over the next year

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are never difference "among" such things. It can only be "between".

Answer (score 2):

*In the next year* = at some time in the next 12 months. "I plan to start learning French in the next year."

*For the next year* = for the whole of the year. "Mr Smith was elected chairman for the next year."

*Over the next year* could mean the same, or at intervals during the year. "He will chair ten meetings over the next year."